# Acompanhar a saída SQL em Java

Tags: java, sql, jsf, padrão-dao

Meu aplicativo em java para web dá várias vezes o erro de `SQL Syntax`, mas só indica um treco do script SQL que dá erro.

Há alguma forma de eu ver o script completo que foi "jogado" no `MySQL` que deu erro? Tipo, ele fala que tem erro na cláusula `WHERE`. Como posso ver tudo que o [java](/questions/tagged/java) montou para executar, desde o `INSERT`?

Comment: você está utilizando jsf?

Comment: Está usando o padrão DAO? As queries são montadas manualmente ou está usando uma maneira automatizada?

Comment: Utilizando padrão DAO e jsf sim.

Answer (score 3):

Se você estiver montando as queries manualmente, você pode imprimir o conteúdo do seu preparedStatement.

```
System.out.println(preparedStatement);
```

Caso estiver usando Hibernate, você pode habilitar o show_sql na tag properties do hibernate.cfg.xml, ou no persistence.xml do JPA.

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
```